Can't create a Merkle Tree with some ValidDepthSizePairs
I was trying to create a merkle tree with maxDepth: 13 and maxBufferSize: 32, it is a valid pair as I can see it in type ValidDepthSizePair here & also in concurrent_merkle_tree_header here
but when I try to send the transaction it shows the following error Failed to get size of max depth 13 and max buffer size 32

what am I doing wrong here?

I think the program is out of date on the network that you're using.
Can you run this locally to see if it works? It looks like the change you need was only deployed to mainnet, since it was last deployed on the day that the 13 / 32 tree change was added, but the testnet and devnet deployments haven't been updated in a long time.
Take a look at https://explorer.solana.com/address/cmtDvXumGCrqC1Age74AVPhSRVXJMd8PJS91L8KbNCK on all clusters, and you'll see the older deployments. The change was only added on 11 October 2023 with https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/5438

I tested on mainnet too, its not working same error

Ah darn, maybe they just never deployed the program with the change -- what about locally?

I can't run that locally as there is no bubblegum program locally. also I confirmed that they didn't upgrade the compression program to the latest version on any cluster/network!

Please feel free to submit an issue in that case: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues
